# php - XML DomElement won't prettify

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to create a XML file using php.

When I print my xml it prints it all in one line and not in proper format.

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
**$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->FormatOutput = true;**

$parent = $xml->createElement("foo");
$parent->setAttribute("xmlns", "http://");
$parent->setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$parent->setAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "link");
$xml->appendChild($parent);
$child = $xml->createElement("foo1");
$parent->appendChild($child);
$subchile = $xml->createElement($foo);
$child->appendChild($subchile);
$s_c = $xml->createElement("foo3",$foo3);
$subchile->appendChild($s_c);

echo "<xmp>" . $xml->saveXML() . "<xml>";    
$xml->save($file_name)
```

it prints everything without indentations etc.

I read other questions here and followed the answers but still nothing. Can you help?

Comment: If you need indentation - why you set `preserveWhitespace` to false?

Comment: @u_mulder even when is set to true it doesn't work

Comment: Names of class properties are __casesensitive__, so it must be `formatOutput`

Comment: thanks that actually fixed the problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

changed $xml->FormatOutput = true; ---> $xml->formatOutput = true;